# Unity Ui panels stretching

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hello,Unity ui panels is getting stretched everytime I reopen unity.

Comment: This is a known Unity bug, click on Game view, make sure your screen size is set in top left corner of game view and press play, everything should be back to normal

Comment: Indeed, they have a similar bug if you have more than one monitor.  Just typical Unity comic engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in inspector of the canvas (parent element) `"Canvas Scaler"` and change UI scale mode to *Scale with screen size*.